# Remove sidebar of title frame

Tags: beamer

Is there a way to remove the left side bar of the title frame only.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\author{Me}
\title{Test}
\date{\today}

\usetheme{PaloAlto}

%% This should be set by user
\setbeamersize{text margin left=4cm, text margin right=2cm} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{frame}[plain] \maketitle \end{frame}` or `\begin{frame}[plain] \titlepage \end{frame}`

Comment: Yes, but that would also remove the navigation bar, and I want to keep that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could temporarily redefine the `sidebar` and `sidebar canvas` templates:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\author{Me}
\title{Test}
\date{\today}

\usetheme{PaloAlto}

%% This should be set by user
\setbeamersize{text margin left=4cm, text margin right=2cm} 

\begin{document}
{
  \setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{}
  \addtobeamertemplate{title page}{\hspace*{-3cm}}{}
  \begin{frame}
  \hspace*{-.5\beamersidebarwidth}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \titlepage
  \end{minipage}
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(the title page looks off-centre in this image, but that's just because the OP uses very asymmetrical margins)